How to control animationcurve ease out/in speed?
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Scaling : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToScale;
    public float duration = 1f;
    public Vector3 minSize;
    public Vector3 maxSize;
    public bool scaleUp = false;
    public Coroutine scaleCoroutine;
    public AnimationCurve easeCurve;
    public bool automatic = false;
    public bool coroutineIsRunning = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (automatic)
        {
            if (!coroutineIsRunning)
            {
                Scale();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
            {
                Scale();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Scale()
    {
        scaleUp = !scaleUp;

        if (scaleCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(scaleCoroutine);

        scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime(objectToScale, (scaleUp ? maxSize : minSize), duration));
    }

    private IEnumerator ScaleOverTime(GameObject targetObj, Vector3 toScale, float duration)
    {
        float counter = 0;
        Vector3 startScaleSize = targetObj.transform.localScale;

        coroutineIsRunning = true;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            float curveTime = counter / duration;
            float curveValue = easeCurve.Evaluate(curveTime);
            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, curveValue);

            if (counter >= duration)
            {
                coroutineIsRunning = false;
                // Ensure the final scale is exactly what it should be based on the animation curve's final value.
                targetObj.transform.localScale = toScale;
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }
}

i want to control the ease in/out speed.  the whole scaling should still be 1 or whatever duration i will set it to.  if for example 5 seconds the duration then i want to control also the ease in/out with another float variable.
for example if the duration is 5 for the scaling and then if i will set the ease speed or time to 3 then first i'm stuck here with the logic because now the duration will take 5 + 3 + 3 and not 5 so the whole scaling duration is changing.
second how to set the ease with the animationcurve in/out duration ?
i tried to change in the inspector the animation curve handles after setting the shape to S then i dragged both and tried to play with it but never found how to control the ease in/out to be smooth but with duration.

Doesn't this do what you want? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.EaseInOut.html

You do this not on the curve itself but the keyframes - you can either automatically SmoothTangents of all keyframes, or adjust the weights and tangents of the KeyFrames directly one by one

alternatively you could of course smooth the curveTime itself ... but then I would question the use of an AnimationCurve as a whole ^^ .. float curveTime = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, counter / duration);
